# Excel VBA update chart not visible

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have an excel file which iterates over different excel files to update them and create a PDF file from them.

The macro iterates over rows and opens the files. This code opens the files:

```
Private Sub openFile(row As Integer)
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim wb As Workbook

    filePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\" + allRows(row).filename
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filePath)
    Application.Run "RefreshEntireWorksheet"
    
    Application.OnTime Now + (TimeSerial(0, 1, 59)), "'ThisWorkbook.updateCharts """ & row & "'"
    
    Application.OnTime Now + (TimeSerial(0, 2, 59)), "'ThisWorkbook.createEmail'"
End Sub
```

Now if there are multiple files, only 1 file has the charts properly updated (the file being on the front). It seems like the `updateCharts` code doesn't work at all:

```
Sub updateCharts(row As Integer)
    
    Dim SheetName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    SheetName = "Sheet1"
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With


    Set wb = Workbooks(allRows(row).filename)
    wb.Activate
    wb.Sheets(SheetName).Activate
    For Each cht In wb.Sheets(SheetName).ChartObjects
        cht.Chart.Refresh
        DoEvents
    Next cht
    
End Sub
```

I checked following links for answers, but none helped:

- [Can't refresh a chart in Excel VBA (Excel 2016)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42113581/cant-refresh-a-chart-in-excel-vba-excel-2016)
- [Refresh all charts without blinking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582897/refresh-all-charts-without-blinking)
- [excel chart not updating when data changed by vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51957981/excel-chart-not-updating-when-data-changed-by-vba)
- [Excel 2013 vba refresh chart content after each iteration of For Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964263/excel-2013-vba-refresh-chart-content-after-each-iteration-of-for-loop)

They all suggest to add an `DoEvent`, but that doesn't work. **So the question is, how can I update charts in a different workbook via VBA?**

Comment: When you say: **It seems like the updateCharts code doesn't work at all**, does it throw an error? does it run without an error but nothing happens? Please provide some more details. Also, what is `allRows`? i.e. what data type is it?. You shouldn't use things like `Activate`. If you qualify your workbook/worksheets, you don't need to activate them (unless you are doing that just to see what happens?)

Comment: @Zac The code runs fine without errors, but nothing is happening. The `Activate` parts are already removed as they messed up the resulting PDF. `allRows` is a made up property which simply refers to all the rows. Different columns are different properties. That part is working just fine, its just that charts are not properly updating. From what I gathered so far, it should be enough to trigger a `CellChanged` event, as they aren't triggered on files in the background

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar issues in the past, and have observed that they seem to *increase* as the Version of Excel increments; I *suspect* it is a case of falling afoul of side-effects caused efficiency enhancements elsewhere to speed up the Application in general (reducing unnecessary drawing on the screen, et cetera)

One thing that I have found (sometimes) works is to try and force the Application Window to Refresh/Redraw, by setting the `WindowState` to itself:

```
Application.WindowState = Application.WindowState
```

This is similar to how some people suggest using `ActiveWindow.SmallScroll down:=0`, `ActiveWindow.SmallScroll 0`, `ActiveWindow.SmallScroll`, or `ActiveWindow.SmallScroll down:=1: ActiveWindow.SmallScroll up:=1`

Combining this with the `ScreenUpdating` toggle, and the `DoEvents`, you can create a quick Subroutine like this:

```
Public Sub RedrawScreen()
    Dim ScreenUpdating As Boolean
    ScreenUpdating = Application.ScreenUpdating

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.WindowState = Application.WindowState
    DoEvents

    Application.ScreenUpdating = ScreenUpdating
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried to call your code after refreshing all the charts, but nothing is happening

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Does the Chart show the correct data *after* the macro has run?  There are 2 possibilities here: if the chart shows the wrong stuff even after the macro has finished, then the code for your chart is wrong (what code do you have to update the *table* that the Chart pulls data from?), and my answer does not apply.  If your chart *does* display correctly after the macro has finished, but does not output the correct image *during* the macro, then... well, more investigation needed, because that's what this code was supposed to fix

Comment: The chart doesn't show any data at all, even after the macro finishes. If I go into the file after the macro and trigger an `CellChanged` event, then the correct data is displayed in every chart for that file. It happens only for the files that are not in the foreground. The data for the charts comes from addin formulas which update on file open

Comment: @XtremeBaumer What does your `CellChanged` event code do? Do you need to trigger it manually - either via `Application.Run`, or by changing a Cell and then `DoEvents`ing - as part of the macro?

Comment: The `CellChanged` event code loops through all charts to set the minimum and maximum value of the y-axis. As of now I have no macro way to trigger the `CellChanged` event. I manually type something in a cell and then press enter to trigger the event

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Just set the `.Value` of a Cell to something with `EnableEvents` true, and it should trigger

Comment: Alright, I did that and found a way to have it update. Now the only problem left is to bring each file into the foreground before setting the value. Is there a way to do so with VBA? Like unless I bring the files to the foreground, the value is set, but the charts are not updated then

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Try `Workbook.Activate` or `AppActivate` - but, if properly written, then you shouldn't *need* to have your Workbook in the foreground to work properly

Comment: I managed to properly update the charts with `Workbook.Activate`. If you would update your answer to reflect the final solution, I can accept it

Comment: Rather than `Workbook.Activate`, could you not use `Workbook.Calculate` to trigger the events?

Comment: @Zac `Workbook.Calculate` doesn't exist as a method. [No entry in docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook)

Comment: I tried a few ways to calculate the workbook/worksheet now, and none of them work. The only one working is still to activate the workbook and write value in a cell

Comment: Sorry that was my bad. It's [`Worksheet.Calculate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.calculate(method))

Comment: @Zac that was part of my tries, but didn't work as needed. I will roll with activating the workbook, setting a value in a cell and running Chronocidal's `RedrawScreen` function for now

Answer (score 0):

Try this (it works for me - Excel 2016):
DoEvents must be in your code as others said before
Delete all colours of the cells of the spreadsheet: all the background of the cells must be "no background"; use only automatic colour (black) for the text of all the cells.
Save, close and reopen the file. Now start your macro and look at your chart.
I don't know why it works, but.........it works!
For those more capable than me: do the opposite: if your chart is updating with your macro running, try to colour some text or some cells. The chart will not update anymore. The Microsoft experts should check what is happening.
Hope this helps. Bye, bb.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).